# StreamTransformationFilter: invalid PKCS #7 block padding found in AES decryption

Tags: c++, aes, crypto++

I want to use AES-256 encryption/decryption in my C++ code to do that I use cryptoPP library, I have implement encryption and decryption. but I get `Error : StreamTransformationFilter: invalid PKCS #7 block padding found` Error.

The senario which I test is :

First I encrypt myplaintext then decrypt it --> there is no error here.

Second I decrypt the cipher created above --> here I got the error.

I know that there are same question here but I couldn't solve my problem :(

Here I set iv:

```
byte iv[16];
string strIv = "162169848599E7C792BF58BFA53D88E6";
memcpy(iv, strIv.data(), strIv.length());
```

Encryption:

```
string CryptoAES::Encrypt(string plain, string strkey) {
    cout << "\nplain text :" << plain;
    cout << "\n key to encrypt: " <<strkey;
    byte key[AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH];
    memcpy(key, strkey.data(), strkey.length());
    string encodedKey, decodedKey,ciphertextEncode,ciphertext;
    encodedKey.clear();
    decodedKey.clear();
    ciphertextEncode.clear();
    ciphertext.clear();
    StringSource(key, sizeof (key), true, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(encodedKey))); 
    StringSource ssk(encodedKey, true, new HexDecoder(new StringSink(decodedKey)));
    memcpy(key, decodedKey.data(), decodedKey.length());
    CryptoPP::AES::Encryption aesEncryption(key, AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption(aesEncryption, iv);

    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink(ciphertext));
    stfEncryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*> (plain.c_str()), plain.length() + 1);
    stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();
    StringSource ss(ciphertext, true, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(ciphertextEncode)));
    cout << "\nencrypted text: " <<ciphertextEncode;
    return ciphertextEncode;
}
```

Decryption:

```
string CryptoAES::Decrypt(string cipher, string strkey) {
    cout <<"\ncipher text : "<< cipher;
    cout << "\n key to decrypt: " <<strkey;
    byte key[AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH];
    memcpy(key, strkey.data(), strkey.length());
    string encodedKey, decodedKey,ciphertextDecode,decryptedtext;
    encodedKey.clear();
    decodedKey.clear();
    ciphertextDecode.clear();
    decryptedtext.clear();
    StringSource(key, sizeof (key), true, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(encodedKey))); 
    StringSource ssk(encodedKey, true, new HexDecoder(new StringSink(decodedKey)));
    memcpy(key, decodedKey.data(), decodedKey.length());
    StringSource ss(cipher, true, new HexDecoder(new StringSink(ciphertextDecode)));
    CryptoPP::AES::Decryption aesDecryption(key, AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption cbcDecryption(aesDecryption, iv);

    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfDecryptor(cbcDecryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink(decryptedtext));
    stfDecryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*> (ciphertextDecode.c_str()), ciphertextDecode.size());
    stfDecryptor.MessageEnd();

    cout <<"\ndecrypted text: "<<decryptedtext;
    return decryptedtext;
}
```

result :

```
plain text :F7ACA191B43AFAF85277DD196FE0441CB7C0901BEC33CB9F38FFAA54CBF219B9
 key to encrypt: 123456
encrypted text: 6FC1BF3108B0590367E6449B6E615CACFDF4DE16EDD05742C873EE4E8A16BA9EC0B8EFAD800F466EE9A6F75202C8800CF4CBDD2620956020D5B0A6A9A8DCEA9EDB5C470527423ACBEEDD0A9C59916C8B
cipher text : 6FC1BF3108B0590367E6449B6E615CACFDF4DE16EDD05742C873EE4E8A16BA9EC0B8EFAD800F466EE9A6F75202C8800CF4CBDD2620956020D5B0A6A9A8DCEA9EDB5C470527423ACBEEDD0A9C59916C8B
 key to decrypt: 123456
decrypted text: F7ACA191B43AFAF85277DD196FE0441CB7C0901BEC33CB9F38FFAA54CBF219B9
cipher text : 6FC1BF3108B0590367E6449B6E615CACFDF4DE16EDD05742C873EE4E8A16BA9EC0B8EFAD800F466EE9A6F75202C8800CF4CBDD2620956020D5B0A6A9A8DCEA9EDB5C470527423ACBEEDD0A9C59916C8B                                                                                                    
 key to decrypt: 123456
exception in proxy server! :( 
    Error : StreamTransformationFilter: invalid PKCS #7 block padding found
```

EDIT #1:
here is the new version of the methods:

IV:

```
for (int i = 0; i < AES::BLOCKSIZE; i++)
        iv[i] = 0;
```

encryption:

```
string CryptoAES::Encrypt(string plain, string strkey) {

    byte key[AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH];
    byte* k = (byte*) strkey.c_str();

    for (int i = 0; i < AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH; i++)
        if (i<sizeof (k))
            key[i] = k[i];
        else
            key[i] = 0;
    string ciphertextEncode,ciphertext;
    cout << "\nplain text :" << plain;
    cout << "\n key to encrypt: " <<key;
    ciphertextEncode.clear();
    ciphertext.clear();
    CryptoPP::AES::Encryption aesEncryption(key, AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption(aesEncryption, iv);

    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink(ciphertext));
    stfEncryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*> (plain.c_str()), plain.length() + 1);
    stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();
    cout << "\nencrypted text: " <<ciphertext;
    StringSource ss(ciphertext, true, new HexEncoder(new StringSink(ciphertextEncode)));
    cout << "\nencoded encrypted text: " <<ciphertextEncode;
    return ciphertextEncode;
}
```

Decryption:

```
string CryptoAES::Decrypt(string cipher, string strkey) {

    byte key[AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH];
    byte* k = (byte*) strkey.c_str();

    for (int i = 0; i < AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH; i++)
        if (i<sizeof (k))
            key[i] = k[i];
        else
            key[i] = 0;
    string ciphertextDecode,decryptedtext;
    cout <<"\ncipher text : "<< cipher;
    cout << "\n key to decrypt: " <<key;
    ciphertextDecode.clear();
    decryptedtext.clear();

    StringSource ss(cipher, true, new HexDecoder(new StringSink(ciphertextDecode)));
    cout << "\n cipher decoded: " << ciphertextDecode;
    CryptoPP::AES::Decryption aesDecryption(key, AES::MAX_KEYLENGTH);
    CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Decryption cbcDecryption(aesDecryption, iv);

    CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfDecryptor(cbcDecryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink(decryptedtext));
    stfDecryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*> (ciphertextDecode.c_str()), ciphertextDecode.size());
    stfDecryptor.MessageEnd();

    cout <<"\ndecrypted text: "<<decryptedtext;
    return decryptedtext;
}
```

result:

```
plain text :0C469BEA09DFCAC0A555E74175F1A614F471A5205FEB13A72C2DFFE8C4B52AA4
 key to encrypt: 123456
encrypted text: �����z�����_���d�0�kߨ���^G�o���zL��Z��fc�L��X���,<X*-R_��x��?�  �U$�
encoded encrypted text: D8F68E8E8B7AADB094A5BD5FC117BFBA648130E46BDFA8B6DD0EA35E17478F6FA01AA38E0417B4087A4CAEBB5AB8C466639C4C84F35895C07FB2172C3C582A2D525FFDDC78A9F83FEFA50913E55524C1
cipher text : D8F68E8E8B7AADB094A5BD5FC117BFBA648130E46BDFA8B6DD0EA35E17478F6FA01AA38E0417B4087A4CAEBB5AB8C466639C4C84F35895C07FB2172C3C582A2D525FFDDC78A9F83FEFA50913E55524C1
 key to decrypt: 123456
 cipher decoded: �����z�����_���d�0�kߨ���^G�o���zL��Z��fc�L��X���,<X*-R_��x��?� �U$�
decrypted text: 0C469BEA09DFCAC0A555E74175F1A614F471A5205FEB13A72C2DFFE8C4B52AA4
cipher text : D8F68E8E8B7AADB094A5BD5FC117BFBA648130E46BDFA8B6DD0EA35E17478F6FA01AA38E0417B4087A4CAEBB5AB8C466639C4C84F35895C07FB2172C3C582A2D525FFDDC78A9F83FEFA50913E55524C1                                                                                               
 key to decrypt: 123456
 cipher decoded: �����z�����_���d�0�kߨ���^G�o���zL��Z��fc�L��X���,<X*-R_��x��?� �U$�
exception in proxy server! :( 
    StreamTransformationFilter: invalid PKCS #7 block padding found
```

Comment: @jww, could you help me in this.

Comment: 1. You are using a 32-byte iv, presumably you are expecting  `memcpy` to convert the hexadecimal string, it doesn't. 2. You are using a 6-byte key for a 256-bit key, don't, use the correct length key. 3. Fix the last line in the result to separate the key from the error message, it is confusing as it is.

Comment: You are hex encoding prior to encryption and post encryption, that is not necessary and should not be done. With 64 bytes to encrypt and with PKCS#7 padding the encrypted output should be 80bytes, instead it is double that of 160-bytes. You need to take the time to study CryptoAES.

Comment: @zaph, I have edit the code. but again I get same error, As I want to save the encrypted string to postgres database I should convert the encrypted text in a way that I could store it.

Comment: Encrypted text is not printable and should be displayed in hexadecimal.

Comment: @zaph, I know, I just print it to show that they are same

Comment: here is the [link](http://txt.do/5p34j).

Comment: It is actually a link to `CryptoPP` that is needed in order to know what the default options are.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I find the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I solved the problems.

**first:**

`string cipher` and `string strkey` have `\0` padding.

**second:**

The `iv[16]` value which was share between two methods, is changed! so I set it in each methods.