# StreamTransformationFilter: invalid PKCS #7 block padding found using AES decryption

Tags: c++, encryption, aes, crypto++

I am trying to perform AES decryption using the `crypto++` library. I have an encrypted file whose first 8 bytes are the filelength, subsequent 16 bytes are the initialization vector, and the remaining data is the data of interest. I also have a string representation of my key (which I hash using SHA256)

I get the following error when trying to perform AES decryption:
`StreamTransformationFilter: invalid PKCS #7 block padding found`

I am using the following c++ code:

```
std::string keyStr = "my_key";
std::string infilePath = "my/file/path";


CryptoPP::SHA256 hash;
unsigned char digest[CryptoPP::SHA256::DIGESTSIZE];

hash.CalculateDigest( digest, reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(&keyStr[0]), keyStr.length() );
auto key = CryptoPP::SecByteBlock(digest, CryptoPP::SHA256::DIGESTSIZE);

std::ifstream fin(infilePath, std::ifstream::binary);

// First 8 bytes is the file size
std::vector<char> fileSizeVec(8);
fin.read(fileSizeVec.data(), fileSizeVec.size());

// Read the next 16 bytes to get the initialization vector
std::vector<char> ivBuffer(16);
fin.read(ivBuffer.data(), ivBuffer.size());
CryptoPP::SecByteBlock iv(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(ivBuffer.data()), ivBuffer.size());

// Create a CBC decryptor
CryptoPP::CBC_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Decryption decryption;
decryption.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv);

CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter decryptor(decryption);

std::vector<char> buffer(CHUNK_SIZE, 0);

while(fin.read(buffer.data(), buffer.size())) {
    CryptoPP::SecByteBlock tmp(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(buffer.data()), buffer.size());
    decryptor.Put(tmp, tmp.size());
        }

decryptor.MessageEnd();
size_t retSize = decryptor.MaxRetrievable();

std::vector<char> decryptedBuff;
decryptedBuff.resize(retSize);

decryptor.Get(reinterpret_cast<CryptoPP::byte*>(decryptedBuff.data()), decryptedBuff.size());
```

I am not sure what is giving me the error. I am working off the following python code. When I run the python code with the same input file, it successfully decrypts the file.

```
def decrypt_file(in_filename, out_filename=None):
    key = hashlib.sha256(PASSWORD).digest()
    """loads and returns the embedded model"""
    chunksize = 24 * 1024
    if not out_filename:
        out_filename = os.path.splitext(in_filename)[0]

    with open(in_filename, 'rb') as infile:
        # get the initial 8 bytes with file size
        tmp = infile.read(8)
        iv = infile.read(16)
        decryptor = AES.new(key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        string = b''
        # with open(out_filename, 'wb') as outfile:
        while True:
            chunk = infile.read(chunksize)
            if len(chunk) == 0:
                break
            string += decryptor.decrypt(chunk)
    return string
```

In addition to solving the error, I would also love some general c++ coding feedback on how I can improve.

Thanks in advance!

**Edit:**
It looks like I wasn't reading the input file all the way to the end (as the length of the last chunk is smaller than `CHUNK_SIZE`). The following code now reads the entire file, however I still get the same issue. I have also confirmed that the `IV` and `key` match exactly that produced from the python code.

```
 // Get the length of the file in bytes
fin.seekg (0, fin.end);
size_t fileLen = fin.tellg();
fin.seekg (0, fin.beg);

std::vector<char> buffer(CHUNK_SIZE, 0);
size_t readSize = CHUNK_SIZE;

while(fin.read(buffer.data(), readSize)) {
     CryptoPP::SecByteBlock tmp(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(buffer.data()), CHUNK_SIZE);
     decryptor.Put(tmp, tmp.size());

      std::fill(buffer.begin(), buffer.end(), 0);

      size_t bytesReamining = fileLen - fin.tellg();
      readSize = CHUNK_SIZE < bytesReamining ? CHUNK_SIZE : bytesReamining;

       if (!readSize)
            break;
        }
}
```

Note that I have tried this line as both `CryptoPP::SecByteBlock tmp(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(buffer.data()), CHUNK_SIZE);`
and `CryptoPP::SecByteBlock tmp(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(buffer.data()), readSize);` (Using `CHUNK_SIZE` pads with `0`)

Comment: Note I did come across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762869/streamtransformationfilter-invalid-pkcs-7-block-padding-found-in-aes-decryptio) post which is very similar, but it seems like they are doing things somewhat differently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an encrypted file whose first 8 bytes are the filelength, subsequent 16 bytes are the initialization vector, and the remaining data is the data of interest...

I think I'll just cut to the chase and show you an easier way to do things with the Crypto++ library. The key and iv are hard-coded to simplify the code. The derivation is not needed for the example. By the way, if Python has it, you should consider using [HKDF](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/HKDF) for derivation of the AES key and iv. HKDF has provable security properties.

Crypto++ handles the chunking for you. You don't need to explicitly perform it; see [Pumping Data](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Pumping_Data) on the Crypto++ wiki.

I believe the Python code has a potential padding oracle present due to the use of CBC mode without a MAC. You might consider adding a MAC or using an [Authenticated Encryption](https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/Authenticated_Encryption) mode of operation.

```cxx
#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "filters.h"
#include "osrng.h"
#include "modes.h"
#include "files.h"
#include "aes.h"
#include "hex.h"

#include <string>
#include <iostream>

const std::string infilePath = "test.dat";

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    using namespace CryptoPP;

    const byte key[16] = {
        1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4, 1,2,3,4
    };
    const byte iv[16] = {
        8,7,6,5, 8,7,6,5, 8,7,6,5, 8,7,6,5
    };
    const byte data[] = // 70 characters
        "Now is the time for all good men to come to the aide of their country.";

    HexEncoder encoder(new FileSink(std::cout));
    std::string message;

    // Show parameters
    {        
        std::cout << "Key: ";
        StringSource(key, 16, true, new Redirector(encoder));
        std::cout << std::endl;

        std::cout << "IV: ";
        StringSource(iv, 16, true, new Redirector(encoder));
        std::cout << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Data: ";
        StringSource(data, 70, true, new Redirector(encoder));
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    // Write sample data
    {
        FileSink outFile(infilePath.c_str());
        word64 length = 8+16+70;

        outFile.PutWord64(length, BIG_ENDIAN_ORDER);
        outFile.Put(iv, 16);

        CBC_Mode<AES>::Encryption enc;
        enc.SetKeyWithIV(key, 16, iv, 16);

        StringSource(data, 70, true, new StreamTransformationFilter(enc, new Redirector(outFile)));
    }

    // Read sample data
    {
        FileSource inFile(infilePath.c_str(), true /*pumpAll*/);

        word64 read, l;
        read = inFile.GetWord64(l, BIG_ENDIAN_ORDER);
        if (read != 8)
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to read length");

        SecByteBlock v(16);
        read = inFile.Get(v, 16);
        if (read != 16)
            throw std::runtime_error("Failed to read iv");

        CBC_Mode<AES>::Decryption dec;
        dec.SetKeyWithIV(key, 16, v, 16);

        SecByteBlock d(l-8-16);
        StreamTransformationFilter f(dec, new ArraySink(d, d.size()));
        inFile.CopyTo(f);
        f.MessageEnd();

        std::cout << "Key: ";
        StringSource(key, 16, true, new Redirector(encoder));
        std::cout << std::endl;

        std::cout << "IV: ";
        StringSource(v, 16, true, new Redirector(encoder));
        std::cout << std::endl;

        std::cout << "Data: ";
        StringSource(d, d.size(), true, new Redirector(encoder));
        std::cout << std::endl;

        message.assign(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(d.data()), d.size());
    }

    std::cout << "Message: ";
    std::cout << message << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Running the program results in:

```
$ g++ test.cxx ./libcryptopp.a -o test.exe
$ ./test.exe
Key: 01020304010203040102030401020304
IV: 08070605080706050807060508070605
Data: 4E6F77206973207468652074696D6520666F7220616C6C20676F6F64206D656E20746F2063
6F6D6520746F207468652061696465206F6620746865697220636F756E7472792E

Key: 01020304010203040102030401020304
IV: 08070605080706050807060508070605
Data: 4E6F77206973207468652074696D6520666F7220616C6C20676F6F64206D656E20746F2063
6F6D6520746F207468652061696465206F6620746865697220636F756E7472792E

Message: Now is the time for all good men to come to the aide of their country.
```

---

Prior to this Stack Overflow question, the Crypto++ library did not provide `PutWord64` and `GetWord64`. Interop with libraries like Python is important to the project, so they were added at [Commit 6d69043403a9](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/6d69043403a9) and [Commit 8260dd1e81c3](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp/commit/8260dd1e81c3). They will be part of the Crypto++ 8.3 release.

If you are working with Crypto++ 8.2 or below, you can perform the 64-bit read with the following code.

```
word64 length;
word32 h, l;

inFile.GetWord32(h, BIG_ENDIAN_ORDER);
inFile.GetWord32(l, BIG_ENDIAN_ORDER);

length = ((word64)h << 32) | l;
```

---

Here is the data file used for this example.

```
$ hexdump -C test.dat
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 5e  08 07 06 05 08 07 06 05  |.......^........|
00000010  08 07 06 05 08 07 06 05  b0 82 79 ee a6 d8 8a 0e  |..........y.....|
00000020  a6 b3 a4 7e 63 bd 9a bc  0e e4 b6 be 3e eb 36 64  |...~c.......>.6d|
00000030  72 cd ba 91 8d e0 d3 c5  cd 64 ae c0 51 de a7 c9  |r........d..Q...|
00000040  1e a8 81 6d c0 d5 42 2a  17 5a 19 62 1e 9c ab fd  |...m..B*.Z.b....|
00000050  21 3d b0 8f e2 b3 7a d4  08 8d ec 00 e0 1e 5e 78  |!=....z.......^x|
00000060  56 6d f5 3e 8c 5f fe 54                           |Vm.>._.T|
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the issue had to do with padding. I instead switched to using a `StringSource`, which only worked once I specified `CryptoPP::BlockPaddingSchemeDef::BlockPaddingScheme::ZEROS_PADDING` as an argument for `StreamTransformationFilter`

Here is the working code for anyone that is interested:

```
    void Crypto::decryptFileAES(CryptoPP::SecByteBlock key, std::string infilePath) {
        std::ifstream fin(infilePath, std::ifstream::binary);

        // Get the length of the file in bytes
        fin.seekg (0, fin.end);
        size_t fileLen = fin.tellg();
        fin.seekg (0, fin.beg);

        // First 8 bytes is the file size
        std::vector<char> fileSizeVec(8);
        fin.read(fileSizeVec.data(), fileSizeVec.size());

        // Read the first 16 bytes to get the initialization vector
        std::vector<char> ivBuffer(16);
        fin.read(ivBuffer.data(), ivBuffer.size());
        CryptoPP::SecByteBlock iv(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(ivBuffer.data()), ivBuffer.size());

        // Create a CBC decryptor
        CryptoPP::CBC_Mode<CryptoPP::AES>::Decryption decryption;
        decryption.SetKeyWithIV(key, sizeof(key), iv);

        size_t bytesReamining = fileLen - fin.tellg();
        std::vector<char> buffer(bytesReamining);

        if(!fin.read(buffer.data(), bytesReamining)) {
            throw std::runtime_error("Unable to read file");
        }

        std::string decryptedText;

        CryptoPP::StringSource ss(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(buffer.data()), buffer.size(), true,
                new CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter(decryption,
                        new CryptoPP::StringSink(decryptedText), CryptoPP::BlockPaddingSchemeDef::BlockPaddingScheme::ZEROS_PADDING));

        std::cout << decryptedText << std::endl;
    }
```