# CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter memory leak possible

Tags: c++, crypto++

I try to integrate the latest version of CryptoPP into UE4 and follow the example in the Wiki, but an error occurred on line 226

https://www.cryptopp.com/wiki/CFB_Mode

```
222 CFB_Mode< AES >::Encryption e;
223 e.SetKeyWithIV(key_byte, sizeof(key_byte), iv_byte);
224
225 StringSource ss(plain, true,
226     new StreamTransformationFilter(e,
227         new StringSink(cipher), BlockPaddingSchemeDef::DEFAULT_PADDING
228     )
229 );
```

Error message:
line 589 of CryptoPP::filters.cpp

```
588 const bool authenticatedFilter = dynamic_cast<AuthenticatedSymmetricCipher *>(&c) != NULLPTR;
589 if (authenticatedFilter)
590     throw InvalidArgument("StreamTransformationFilter: please use AuthenticatedEncryptionFilter and AuthenticatedDecryptionFilter for AuthenticatedSymmetricCipher");
```

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFF04DA5D20 (vcruntime140.dll) in UE4Editor.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x000000BFC2AE405C. occurred
```

stack trace:

```
attachment  Variable is optimized away and not available.
```

I also used another way of writing

[StreamTransformationFilter: invalid PKCS #7 block padding found in AES decryption](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34762869/14026593)

In the above link, this method did not cause an error in the encryption

```
230 StreamTransformationFilter stf(e, new StringSink(cipher));
231 stf.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(plain.c_str()), plain.length() + 1);
232 stf.MessageEnd();
```

But it still gives the same error

I don't know how to solve this problem

In order to ensure the unity of the problem, I list some of my settings

CryptoPP 8.2

using static lib

Answer (score -2):

Just Switch your Project Configuration to Debug mode in Visual Studio, this error will be removed.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VFKPm.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. There is very little context to that screenshot, which might not be helpful for a user. Also, that will only prevent variables from being optimized away - and will not prevent the user's error.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Debug mode might solve "variable optimized away", but will hardly solve the invalid pointer problem.